# How to create admin page and api/v1 in symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, bundle, admin, symfony-forms

this is my forder structure [project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAR4L.png)
this is my routing config

this is my routing config

```html
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   admin/
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Default:index }
```

Hi guys!
This is my project
but I go to link http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
I get message
No route found for "GET /admin"
Please help me
Sorry my english is not very well
Thanks Guy

Comment: Try to change prefix to `/admin` and do not forget to `clear:cache`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Default:index }
```

(slash before admin and typo on AdminBunlde)